Eigenvalues and Eigenfunctions for a Boundary Value Problem
I am trying to determine the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions for the following boundary value problem:
\begin{equation*}
\frac{d^2 y}{d x^2}+\left(\lambda-x^2\right) y=0
\end{equation*}
subject to the boundary conditions $y(0)=0$ and $y(1)=0$.
Could someone explain how to approach this problem and find the eigenvalues $\lambda$ and the corresponding eigenfunctions $y(x)$ ?

Does the method of Frobenius suggest anything?

@Aruralreader That idea looks promising, I'll give it a try :)

You can find the general solution to the ODE here.

Asymptotic analysis suggests the solution has the form $y=H(x)e^{-x^2/2}$. Substituting and re-arranging, one finds an equation for $H(x)$ which satisfies Hermite's Equation with the solutions being Orthogonal Polynomials, specifically Hermite Polynomials. Then the method of Rodrigues allows for the generation of more solutions. This equation pays a key role in solving the Quantum Harmonic Oscillator Schrodinger Equation. A series solution can be used to solve the Hermite Equation. I think this is better than Froby, fewer steps required.

General solution of the ODE is
$$y\! \left(x\right)=\frac{c_{1} \mathrm{WhittakerM}\! \left(\frac{\lambda}{4},\frac{1}{4},x^{2}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}+\frac{c_{2} \mathrm{WhittakerW}\! \left(\frac{\lambda}{4},\frac{1}{4},x^{2}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}$$
We have the boundary conditions $y(0)=y(1)=0$:
$$y(0)=0 \implies c_2=0$$
$$y(1)=0 \implies \mathrm{WhittakerM}\! \left(\frac{\lambda}{4},\frac{1}{4},1\right)=0$$
Hence, the eigenfunctions are
$$y_{\lambda}(x)=c(\lambda)\cdot\frac{\mathrm{WhittakerM}\! \left(\frac{\lambda}{4},\frac{1}{4},x^{2}\right)}{\sqrt{x}}$$
We want to get an orthonormal basis, such that
$$\int_0^1 y_{\lambda}(x)^2\; dx=1 \implies c(\lambda)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\int_0^1 y_{\lambda}(x)^2\; dx}}$$
Eigenvalues $\lambda_n$ are the roots of equation
$$\mathrm{WhittakerM}\! \left(\frac{\lambda_n}{4},\frac{1}{4},1\right)=0$$
$$\lambda_n= \bigg[10.151164030453566132, 39.799393003660177613, 89.154342456267011880, 158.24396170714367106,
 247.07150022803182210, 355.63774380637945144, 483.94295928009770180, 631.98725757544127386,... \bigg]$$
Plot the first 8 eigenfunctions:

